# Is Dart Dev Compiler supposed to support dart:io?

Tags: dart, dart-dev-compiler

I tried compiling a simple `HttpServer.bind` with DDC and it seems to throw a runtime error saying "Operation not supported" on that line.

Am I doing something wrong, or is DDC not supposed to support that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart Dev Compiler does not support `dart:io`. It is only for web applications.